# Converting to multiple file upload at once from single file input types. Newb Stuff

Tags: php, upload

I have a script that uploads images via a form. I want to go from:

```
<input type="file" name="img_1_upload" class="text">
<input type="file" name="img_2_upload" class="text">
<input type="file" name="img_3_upload" class="text">
<input type="file" name="img_4_upload" class="text">
<input type="file" name="img_5_upload" class="text">
<input type="file" name="img_6_upload" class="text">
```

To using the multiple upload input type via:

```
<input name="images[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
```

My PHP script detects images inputted with names = img_1_upload,img_2_upload,img_3_upload... all the way up to img_6_upload...

However using the multiple file input type, I am unable to set the name of each file to the format img_1_upload,.. and so on.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Have you inspected `$_FILES` yet?  It changes format when dealing with multiple files...

Comment: Change your PHP script to use the new names. What is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function? The files uploaded are temporary files anyhow. You probably need to move them to a more appropriate location. While moving, you can also rename the files to whatever you want.

P.S: I assume you know that you can access the name of the files using `$_FILES["images"]["name"][index]` where index is the array index from 0 to number of files - 1.

P.S2: Also make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES array contains the information for uploaded files. When uploading multiple files $_FILES is structured like;
Array

```
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo.txt
            [1] => bar.txt
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/plain
            [1] => text/plain
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
        )
)
```

You can then rename the files as you like with a simple `foreach()` loop.